# Google Tag Manager and sending data offline

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, web-analytics

I have a question to the following case. We want to track a content platform using google tag manager. However, not every time the platform is online but GTM would send data to our internal server. Therefore our concern is if data collected during this offline period will be kept or if we loose them. 
Do you know if there is some period during which data collected offline through Google Tag Manager is kept and once it gets online then it is sent to Google Analytics?

Thank you,

Lukas

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not how Google Tag Manager works. GTM for web is basically a javascript injection engine. It bundles your configured tags,triggers and variables with a selector engine and injects that into your page. There is no serverside component that stores data.

I'm sure one could come up with a solution to your problem - e.g. store your data with localstorage in the browser, poll you server to see if it is available, and when it's online send the data with a [queue time parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt) to Google Analytics. However that has nothing to do with GTM.

Having said this, it is hard to understand your use case - if your server is offline, then where does the data come from ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an offline PWA app (with a Service Worker), you can use the [Workbox Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-google-analytics) module to handle the collection of data, and to report it upstream when your site comes back online.

This module has a service worker fetch handler that intercepts the calls that you would make with `analytics.js` or `gtag.js`, and stores your data locally in IndexDB in the event that the call fails because it is offline.